# Struts 2 : onclick not working in s:submit tag

Tags: struts2, onclick, form-submit, sanitization

I am using Struts 2 (2.3.32) .

Having simple struts form with submit tag of struts,

```
<s:text type="text" onclick="callme()" id ="1">
<s:submit type="button" onclick="callme()" id ="2 ">
```

These statements after rendering on html page, first one works but for submit it gets rendered to

```
<input type="submit" click:onclick()="" id="2">
```

It works for simple text field ,

```
<input type="text" onclick="callme()" id ="1">
```

Can some one point out , whats  wrong with this ?
Any sanitation added in struts 2.3.16 ?

It was working in Struts 2.3.15.x

Comment: Are you using some frontend framework? Also `<s:text>` will not render `<input type="text">`.

Comment: Yes, struts tag library is used .

<%@ include file="/features/common/include/resources/struts-tags.jsp"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>